# Jtree node addition

Tags: java, database, swing, jtree

JTree created by me populates from databases.
I want to add new node which I am able to create insertNodeInto() function.
Now how do I change the underlying database?

1. Add node first via treemodel and then do the insert in database
2. Insert into database and then recreate the tree.

I would like to know the steps involved in case (1) above as the tree I created has large number of nodes.

Comment: as you said tree is excessive so i raise my hand for (a). After adding the node to the tree, create the query and process it on to the database. Or you can do another way: insert to database -> insert this node to the tree. As long as you keep record of it, it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

I would add it first to the database. The reason is that if the DB insert fails for some reason (constraints for example) and you get an SQLException, the user should not get the impression that the insert was successful.

Of course, you don't need to recreate the tree, you can just add another node at any time.